# Dealing with Missing Data within a String

Tags: python, string, csv

Suppose that I have a long string, S, that looks like:

```
S = "A, 2001, 2003, 2005, A, 2002, A, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, A, 2001, 2002, A, 2001, 2006, 2004, A..."
```

Using Python, how does one obtain the following string:

```
"A, 2001, 2003, 2005, , A, 2002, , , , A, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, A, 2001, 2002, , , A, 2001, 2006, 2004, , A..."
```

where I want the number of "columns" (i.e., commas) equal to the maximum number of years that appear between the two As.

The motivation here is to create a sensibly-ordered CSV file.

I want to break this up into a list and then loop through, adding commas to each element if the length of the element is less than say 4 in this example.

Comment: By "columns", do you mean number of commas?

Comment: Your sample input and desired output does not seem to match the description, or I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Do you mean there should be a fixed number of years between each 'A' and you want to insert commas if some years are missing?

Answer (score 1):

First, split your initial string into elements, then create a two dimension array and calculate max length. Then you can merge them back while adding missing cells. Something like:

```
S = "A, 2001, 2003, 2005, A, 2002, A, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, A, 2001, 2002, A, 2001, 2006, 2004"

elems = S.split(', ')
lines = []
line = []
length = 0
maxlength = 0
for elem in elems[1:]:
    if 'A' == elem:
        lines.append(line)
        line = []
        if length > maxlength:
            maxlength = length
        length = 0
    else:
        line.append(elem)
        length += 1
lines.append(line)

for line in lines:
    line.extend([''] * (maxlength - len(line)))
    line.insert(0, 'A')

print ','.join(map(lambda x : ','.join(x), lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be hard pressed without temporary storage to get away from the 2 passes since we don't know the max length at the beginning:

```
s = "A, 2001, 2003, 2005, A, 2002, A, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, A, 2001, 2002, A, 2001, 2006, 2004, A..."
parts = s.split('A,')
parts.pop(0) # first is empty
xlen  = max([len(x.split(',')) for x in parts])
for x in parts:
  have  = x.count(',')
  print "A, " + x + (", " * (xl - have - 1))
```

And the output:

```
A,  2001, 2003, 2005, , 
A,  2002, , , , 
A,  2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
A,  2001, 2002, , , 
A,  2001, 2006, 2004, A...,
```

Comment: wow.  thanks so much for this!  that there exists this community of such generous intelligent people maintains a sometimes faltering faith in the goodness of humanity.